# Parse tab delimited CSV file to array of hashes in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, csv, hash

I have the following code:

```
  def csv_to_array(file)
    csv = CSV::parse(file)
    fields = csv.shift
    array = csv.collect { |record| Hash[*fields.zip(record).flatten] }
  end
```

This creates an array of hashes, and works fine with comma separated values. I am trying to replicate this code for a tab delimited file. Currently, when I run the above code on my tab delimited file, I get something like this:

```
array[0] = {"First Name\tLast Name\tCode\t"=>"Luigi\tSmith\t1406\t"}
```

So, each array object is a hash as intended, but it has one key value pair - The entire tab delimited header row being the key, and the individual row of data being the value.

How can I alter this code to return an array of hashes with individual key value pairs, with the header of each column mapping to the row value for that column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the options you pass to parse are listed in [::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new)

```
>> CSV.parse("qwe\tq\twe", col_sep: "\t"){|a| p a}
["qwe", "q", "we"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `col_sep` option, this post has the code: [Changing field separator/delimiter in exported CSV using Ruby CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821843/changing-field-separator-delimiter-in-exported-csv-using-ruby-csv?answertab=active#tab-top)

also checkout the docs: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

lots of good stuff in the [DEFAULT_OPTIONS](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#DEFAULT_OPTIONS) section