# Ruby: Using an array list in order to select specific columns

Tags: ruby

I'm new in Ruby.
Here the script, I would like to use the selector in line 10 instead of fields[0] etc...
How can I do that ?

For the example the data are embedded.
Don't hesitate to correct me if I'm doing wrong when I'm opening or writing a file or anything else, I like to learn.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

filename = "/tmp/log.csv"

selector = [0, 3, 5, 7]

out = File.open(filename + ".rb.txt", "w")
DATA.each_line do |line|
        fields = line.split("|")
        columns = fields[0], fields[3], fields[5], fields[7]
        puts columns.join("|")
        out.puts(columns.join("|"))
end
out.close


__END__
20180704150930|rtsp|645645643|30193|211|KLM|KLM00SD624817.ts|172.30.16.34|127299264|VERB|01780000|21103|277|server01|OK
20180704150931|api|456456546|30130|234|VC3|VC300179201139.ts|172.30.16.138|192271838|VERB|05540000|23404|414|server01|OK
20180704150931|api|465456786|30154|443|BAD|BAD004416550.ts|172.30.16.50|280212202|VERB|04740000|44301|18|server01|OK
20180704150931|api|5437863735|30157|383|VSS|VSS0011062009.ts|172.30.16.66|312727922|VERB|05700000|38303|381|server01|OK
20180704150931|api|3453432|30215|223|VAE|VAE00TF548197.ts|172.30.16.74|114127126|VERB|05060000|22305|35|server01|OK
20180704150931|api|312121|30044|487|BOV|BOVVAE00549424.ts|172.30.16.58|69139448|VERB|05300000|48708|131|server01|OK
20180704150931|rtsp|453432123|30127|203|GZD|GZD0900032066.ts|172.30.16.58|83164150|VERB|05460000|20303|793|server01|OK
20180704150932|api|12345348|30154|465|TYH|TYH0011224259.ts|172.30.16.50|279556843|VERB|04900000|46503|241|server01|OK
20180704150932|api|4343212312|30154|326|VAE|VAE00TF548637.ts|172.30.16.3|28966797|VERB|04740000|32601|969|server01|OK
20180704150932|api|312175665|64530|305|TTT|TTT000000011852.ts|172.30.16.98|47868183|VERB|04740000|30501|275|server01|OK
```

Comment: does this CSV have headers?

Comment: No, there is no header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin with a more manageable example. First note that if your string is held by the variable `data`, each line of the string contains the same number (14) of vertical bars (`'|'`). Lets reduce that to the first 4 lines of `data` with each line terminated immediately before the 6th vertical bar:

```
str = data.each_line.map { |line| line.split("|").first(6).join("|") }.first(4).join("\n")
puts str
20180704150930|rtsp|645645643|30193|211|KLM
20180704150931|api|456456546|30130|234|VC3
20180704150931|api|465456786|30154|443|BAD
20180704150931|api|5437863735|30157|383|VSS
```

We need to also modify `selector` (arbitrarily):

```
selector = [0, 3, 4]
```

Now on to answering the question.

There is no need to divide the string into lines, split each line on the vertical bars, select the elements of interest from the resulting array, join the latter with a vertical bar and then lastly join the whole shootin' match with a newline (*whew!*). Instead, simply use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to remove all unwanted characters from the string.

```
terms_per_row = str.each_line.first.count('|') + 1
  #=> 6
r = /
    (?:^|\|)  # match the beginning of a line or a vertical bar in a non-capture group
    [^|\n|]+  # match one or more characters other than a vertical bar or newline
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

line_idx = -1
new_str = str.gsub(r) do |s|
  line_idx += 1
  selector.include?(line_idx % terms_per_row) ? s : ''
end
puts new_str
20180704150930|30193|211
20180704150931|30130|234
20180704150931|30154|443
20180704150931|30157|383
```

Lastly, we write `new_str` to file:

```
File.write(fname, new_str)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get `fields` at specific indices using [Ruby's splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html) (search for 'splat') and [Array.values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) like so:

```
columns = fields.values_at(*selector)
```

A couple of coding style suggestions:

1.You may want to make `selector` a constant since its unlikely that you'll want to mutate it further down in your code base

2.The `out` and `out.close` and appending to `DATA` can all be condensed into a [CSV.open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-To+a+File):

```
CSV.open(filenname, 'wb') do |csv|
  columns.map do |col|
    csv << col
  end
end
```

You can also specify a custom delimiter (pipe `|` in your case) as [noted in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822035/3284936) like so:

```
...
  CSV.open(filenname, 'wb', {col_sep: '|') do |csv|
...
```

Comment: That's perfect, Thanks.