# How to Change Delimeter of a Csv file

Tags: bash, unix

I need to change the delimiter of a csv file from comma(,) to Pipe(|) Symbol.

Note: Here file separator is also coming inside data string. I need to skip that value i tried one command But it is changing insider comma also `awk '$1=$1' FS="," OFS=":" Sample.csv` (I tried this but not giving expected output)

Input > Sample.csv

```
Col1, Col2, Col3 , Col4
101, XYZ, 2020 , "Hello, World"
102, PQR, 2021, "Help, Me"
```

Output > Sample_Out.csv should be like.

```
Col1| Col2| Col3|Col4
101 | XYZ | 2020 | "Hello, World"
102 | PQR |2021 | "Help, Me"
```

Comment: Here's a Python solution if you don't get lucky https://stackoverflow.com/a/21527170/2836621

Answer (score 1):

Try this, special handling of double quotes is needed, so split the fields with it, process alternate field and replace the comma to pipe.

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",","|",$i)}1' FS=\" OFS=\" Sample.csv
```

Output:

```
Col1| Col2| Col3 | Col4
101| XYZ| 2020 | "Hello, World"
102| PQR| 2021| "Help, Me"
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is for raw text processing and therefore cannot handle commas in quotes. Instead, you should use tools designed for csv like `csvtool`:

```
csvtool -u \| -t , cat Sample.csv > Sample_Out.csv
```

From `csvtool` doc:

> -t Input separator char.
>
> -u Output separator char.

> cat
>
> This concatenates the input files together and writes them to
> the output.  You can use this to change the separator character.
>
> ```
>  Example: csvtool -t TAB -u COMMA cat input.tsv > output.csv
> ```

Otherwise you may follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821843/5223223) by using `ruby`. You can also use `python` or other programming languages that handles csv files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some actions to take care of these quoted commas.
You can start changing them into something else :

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "§", $i) } 1' Sample.csv
```

Then you can change the remaining commas into whatever you want :

```
awk '$1=$1' FS="," OFS=":" Sample.csv
```

And you change the § into the commas before it

```
awk '$1=$1' FS="§" OFS="," Sample.csv
```

I think you can make a awk file and put all the steps into it.